# jquery serializeArray() not created using semantic-ui framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, jscript, semantic-ui

I am creating semantic UI. I want serialize array value when i click submit button. I am having two textbox for Username and password. i enter some values in both textbox. when i click submit button, i want serialize array conversion for Json format. But i have done some code. But its not working. Perhaps i dont know exact way. Any one please help?

And also i want how to send the serilize to Json Url for WCF services.

```
<div class="ui small signin modal">
        <i class="circular inverted teal close icon"></i>
          <div class="column">
            <div class="ui fluid form segment sub_form">
              <h3 class="ui header">Sign In</h3>
                <div class="field">
                  <div class="ui left labeled icon input">
                    <input type="text" id="txtUserName" placeholder="username" name="login_name">
                    <i class="user icon"></i>
                    <div class="ui corner label">
                      <i class="icon asterisk"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                  <div class="ui left labeled icon input">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="login_psw">
                    <i class="lock icon"></i>
                    <div class="ui corner label">
                      <i class="icon asterisk"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui blue submit button">Login</div>
                <div id="results" class="ui compact message"></div>
                <div id="json_obj" class="ui compact message"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ui.form").submit(function(event) {
    console.log($(this).serializeArray());
    event.preventDefault();
  });
 });
```

Comment: Serialize expects a `form` element and not a `div`. Change it to a form and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend.It works."je-bl-u" @bencripps

Answer (score 1):

[.serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) expects a `form` element and not a `div`. Change it to a form and it will work.